# PrestaSitemap bundle generates localhost on production server

Tags: symfony, sitemap, symfony-3.3

I'm using Presta SiteMap Bundle for generating sitemaps on my site, but when it generates to me sitemaps on prod server path to sitemaps looks like below:
`http://localhost/sitemap.holidayideas.xml`

What should I write in config or anywhere in my app to generate correct url's for my sitemaps.

P.S. I'm using Symfony 3.3.2 for my app

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution - need to specify url and protocol in `parameters.yml` as below:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host:   your-domain.com
    router.request_context.scheme: http
```